# there are some way to create a custom scaffold or generator on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I wish to create my custom generator, some like run the command "rails generator myScaffold entity field1:String field2:String

and the generator behavior like a normal scaffold, except it will not create the stylesshets, views, and the class of the controller would be customized.

Is it posible with rails? And is it a good and correct thing to do?

thanks!!!

Comment: `rails g scaffold entity  --no-stylesheets` it will not generate css files

Answer (score -1):

All you need is available here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html